# Rails OpenId (more or less) form scratch

Tags: ruby-on-rails, authentication, openid

I'm looking for a nice, customisable way to authenticate users via OpenID. I'm using [sorcery](https://github.com/NoamB/sorcery) and so far it works like a charm: it has support for email-based login and OAuth-based login. However, it has no support for OpenID, and I wouldn't like to use existing authentication gems like Omniauth and the likes. I also find Ryan Bates' [tutorial](http://railscasts.com/episodes/68-openid-authentication) a bit outdated. Note that I also [did some search](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=rails%20openid) on this topic on SO. All rants date to 2009, and I fear that implementation may not work (I also want to avoid another trial-and-error spike testing).

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

I've been working on [GlitterGallery](https://github.com/sarupbanskota/GlitterGallery). I remember struggling with old docs and had blogged about the route I took to make OpenID login work. You might be interested to look it up [here](http://thirstyforcola.wordpress.com/2013/06/30/setting-up-openid-on-rails/). I'm not sure if there's anything better available now, but I'll be coming back and I'll update the post accordingly; cheers!